manually changing uid:gid of a system app with shared UID
On a Cheap Chinese Android phone  ( a honda civic sold to  me with the price & specs of a Maserati ) , running plain vanilla android - my apps crash arbitrarily and I seem to think the culprit is a chinese app that shares the same uid:gid aka system with other apps that have this uid:gid. So If I pm disable <chinese app> it will disable my launcher toggle button  as well as I cant launch settings .
drwx------ 8 system  system  3488 2024-08-29 00:32 /data/data/com.auroradroid.softmanager

I am rooted. What If I chown it to another non system UID:GID and then disable it. Any idea what happens then in terms of sequelae ?
